# Using cuts in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to find all of the distinct entries where a person's name is john, peter or fred.

However, if there were, for example, two people called peter, I only want to display one occurrence of the name.

My code so far is as follows:

```
searchpeople(X) :-
   people(_,[X|_]),
   X=john; X=peter; X=fred.
```

I understand that the solution is probably something to do with cuts (having read other posts), but I cannot find an example where cuts are used when trying to retrieve X OR Y OR Z (In my case john, peter or fred).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to put round brackets around `X = john ...` otherwise you will always find `peter` and `fred` regardless of what `people/2` describes.

Comment: `setof(t,searchpeople(X),_)`

Comment: I don't really see what you're trying to say here... I want to find peter and fred! I just don't want duplicate values!

As for your setof(t,searchpeople(X),_),

I don't have any idea how to use that!

Comment: Just type the query `setof(t,searchpeople(X),_)` instead of `searchpeople(X)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're confusing operator precedence. Just like more conventional programming languages where writing something like this

```
if ( A and B OR C OR D )
...
```

is almost certainly going to get you in trouble, your code has the exact same problem. Operator precedence and associativity causes

```
searchpeople(X) :-
  people(_,[X|_]) ,
  X=john ;
  X=peter ;
  X=fred .
```

to be parsed as if written

```
searchpeople(X) :-
  ( people(_,[X|_]) ,
    X = john
  ) ;
  ( X = peter ;
    X = fred
  ) .
```

Which is probably not what you intended.

While you *could* use parenthesis to get the effect you most likely want:

```
searchpeople(X) :-
  people(_,[X|_]) ,
  ( X = john ;
    X = peter ;
    X = fred
  ) .
```

You would be better off splitting things up a bit:

```
search_people(X) :-
    people(_,[X|_]) ,
    desired_person(X).

desired_person(john).
desired_person(peter).
desired_person(fred).
```

It makes your intent clearer and easier to understand. It's also easier to debug and extend.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I'm struggling to come to terms with operator precedence having been studying Java for some time! 

I appreciate you explaining associativity issues as well!